# Find clusters based on 2D array

Tags: c#, algorithm, cluster-computing, k-means, matrix-multiplication

Given is a 2D Array, see below.

```
var matrix = new[,]
{
  { 1,1,0,0 },
  { 1,1,1,0 },
  { 0,1,1,1 },
  { 0,0,1,1 }
};
```

Now lets take it on 2D Canvas,

```
                    T0      T1      T2       T3

          T0        1        1       0       0

          T1        1        1       1       0

          T2        0        1       1       1

          T3        0        0       1       1
```

What I want is the transitive pairs of the matrix i.e. {(**T1, T1**), (**T2, T2**), (**T3, T3**)}

see below image, I have done rough sketch of my outputs.

[image]

**What I Have done to achieve this?**

I followed the answer of **Matt Cole** from this question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88670/finding-clusters-in-a-matrix

I get my outputs, but the code is to much as Matt added OO principles.

I want just plain code for it.

**Inputs** : Array[n,m] for example here it's a **Array[4,4]**

**Output**:  Transitive pairs, over here it's {(**T1, T1**), (**T2, T2**), (**T3, T3**)}

Comment: How is this related to clusters?